# php execute shell script via http

Tags: php, shell, apache2, cgi, exec

i have a problem with my php script.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(-1);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $output = "";
 $befehl = exec('./start.sh', $output);
 var_dump($output);
?>
```

This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hallo Europa"
echo "Hallo Osterhase..."
cd /home/support/projects/big/
bash start.sh
pwd
whoami
```

This is working in the shell with 'php run.php'
But not with http://ip/run.php
Apache is running as my home user "max". The server is not public reachable so it is not a security risk. 
The output in Firefox is:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "Hallo Europa" [1]=> string(18) "Hallo    Osterhase..." [2]=> string(31) "/home/support/projects/big" [3]=> string(7) "support" }
```

But it should start my cucumber feature.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: What do you think it should output?

Comment: `support` != `max`

Comment: Do have a permission to execute?

Comment: sorry. I changed my user. There is no max. only support. It doesnt have to output something but i see on my devices that the shell script/cucumber exec is not executed.

Comment: You should match the output to the code you are using; the paths don't match either. And outputting something from `start.sh` would be the first step in troubleshooting this.

Comment: You have two bash scripts called start.sh ? ... Because inside your start.sh (**this is my shell script**) you call also another `start.sh ` ... This is the same or is another `start.sh ` in other directory?

Comment: yes I have a second script named start.sh

Answer (score 1):

First be sure you have execution permission on your .sh script:

`chmod +x /your/full/path/to/start.sh`

After that try:

```
exec("(/your/full/path/to/start.sh) 2>&1", $output, $result);

if($result != 0){
    //if $result is different to 0 -> something wrong and display errors
    print_r([$output,$result]);
}else{
    //if $result == 0 -> Should be OK and continue with your code here
    print_r([$output,$result]);
}
```

Little explanation about `2>&1` from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99264

`2` refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. stderr.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. stdout.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /home/support/projects/big/start.sh: line 7: cucumber: command not found ) [1] => 127 )

Comment: So  the cucumber executable is not on your path

Comment: Check the RubyGems path by running gem env and update your operating system path accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591576/cucumber-command-not-found-error-on-command-line-rake-cucumber-works-fine

Comment: Or better Try to use in your `/home/support/projects/big/start.sh` ... also full path to `cucumber executable` when you call it

Comment: Yes now I got another error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /usr/bin/env: 'ruby': No such file or directory ) [1] => 127 )

Comment: #!/bin/bash
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/support/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/home/support/.rvm$
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y %H:%M:%S")
cd /home/support/projects/big/
mkdir /home/support/projects/big/reports/"rep_$(date +'%F_%T')"
/home/support/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/cucumber --format pretty --format json --out=/home/support/projects/big/reports/"rep_$(date +'%F_%T')"/out.json /home/support/projects/big/features/big.feature -t ~@wip

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cucumber (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException) [1] => from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path' [2] => from /home/support/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `
' ) [1] => 1 )

Comment: So now you can see that `exec()` work as espected but your problem now is about `gem cucumber` ... take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358510/2951051 ... or open a new question about. Sorry I have not experience with ruby

Answer (score 0):

Double quoting is important.

Using `system` is best on this case, as it is holding the complete stdout output in `$output`.

`&` tells the shell to execute the command in a background sub processus.

This means the next line of the script will be directly executed.

The `$output` variable is updated on the background, so the output may be different upon the timing.

```
<?php
$output = system("./start.sh &");
var_dump($output);
```

In many cases, pause timings are useful:

```
<?php
$output = system("./start.sh &");
sleep(1);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Hallo Europa Hallo Osterhase... /home/support/projects/big support string(7) "support"

Comment: Well, following your output, your blocking problem comes from the line `bash start.sh` . The program inside your second start.sh is blocking, maybe stuck in a loop. This said i can tell you that your php code, or mine, is okay like this. 
Please copy the content of the second start.sh, maybe we can help. Try also to `bash start.sh &` just like before. Good luck

Comment: Of course, it may as well tell that your second start.sh is taking more than a second to complete. Try to change the sleep value, like `sleep(10);` for ten seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely need to update your php.ini file to allow `exec()`

Open your php.ini file and find the line that has `disable_functions` and remove `exec` from the list of disabled functions. Save, restart web server and try again.

Comment: How would you explain the OP's output if `exec()` were disabled?

Comment: yes you are right jeroen. It is not to find in disable functions.

Comment: @jeroen php.ini can be set differently for public folders vs. internal. I should have noted that, but I don't think I deserved the downvote :P